# Sprite appearing in node count but not visible

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im attempting to create a constantly moving background by cycling 2 sprites. Running my code shows that the sprites have been added in the correct positions in the correct size. Yet the sprites aren't visible on screen. Why is this the case? My code below

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    var ship = SKSpriteNode()
    var actionMoveRight = SKAction()
    var actionMoveLeft = SKAction()
    let shipCategory = 0x1 << 1
    let obstacleCategory = 0x1 << 2
    let backgroundVelocity : CGFloat = 3.0
    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var background = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "background")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Making self delegate of physics world)
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zero
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        createBG()
        addShip()
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        moveBG()
    }

    func createBG(){
        for i in 0...2{
            background = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "background")
            background.name = "background"
            background.size = CGSize.init(width: (self.scene?.size.width)!, height: (self.scene?.size.height)!)
            background.anchorPoint = self.anchorPoint
            background.position = CGPoint.init(x: CGFloat(i) * background.size.width, y: (-(self.frame.size.height/2)))
            background.zPosition = 0
            self.addChild(background)
        }
    }

    func moveBG(){
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "background", using: ({
            (node, error) in

            node.position.x -= 10
            if node.position.x < (self.scene?.size.width)!{
                node.position.x += (self.scene?.size.width)! * 2
            }
        }))
    }

    func addShip() {
        // Initializing spaceship node
        ship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        ship.setScale(0.2)
        ship.isHidden = false
        ship.zRotation = CGFloat(0)
        // Adding SpriteKit physics body for collision detection
        ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ship.size)
        ship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(shipCategory)
        ship.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        ship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(obstacleCategory)
        ship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        ship.name = "ship"
        ship.position = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: (-(self.frame.size.height/2)) + ship.size.height/2)
        ship.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(ship)
        actionMoveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 5, y: 0, duration: 0.2) //9
        actionMoveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -5  , y: 0, duration: 0.2) //10
        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable == true {
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler:{
                data, error in
                if (data!.acceleration.y) < -0.05 {
                    self.ship.run(self.actionMoveLeft)
                }

                else if data!.acceleration.y > 0.05 {
                    self.ship.run(self.actionMoveRight)
                }

            })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which sprite doesn't?  Background?  Ship?  Or both?

Comment: @ElTomato The background sprite does not show up. The ship does however.

Comment: Tried background.size.width/2?

Comment: There are a few problems.  The critical one is background.position = CGPoint.init(x: CGFloat(i) * background.size.width, y: (-(self.frame.size.height/2))), I think.  Set the count of the background loop to 1 and see if the first background image appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the background node size is just the same as the image size.  I also assume that the scene size is the same as the image size.  If that's the case, try the following.

```
let backTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background")
let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backTexture)
//background.size = CGSize.init(width: (self.scene?.size.width)!, height: (self.scene?.size.height)!)
//background.anchorPoint = self.anchorPoint
background.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * background.size.width, y: 0))
```

Comment: This was close but a few edits were needed. My for loop had to still start at zero and I had to modify my background movement method to keep it from switching images early. Otherwise thank you